# Why ContentEditable is horrible in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am using the div with contenteditable on keypress i am using 15 characters to edit after focus it cant editabl below is the code.
Code:

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="{{isContentEditable}}"  onkeypress="return (this.innerHTML.length <= 15)"
                    ng-blur="handleEditableBlur();" ng-keydown="handleKeydown($event)" > {{value}}                    
                   </div>
                    <span id="pencilIcon" class="fa fa-pencil" data-ng-click="handleEdit();"  focus="test"></span>
```

Here afterclick the pencilicon contenteditable is true after 15 characters is not editable again i can update the content its working fine in chrome not working in firfox

Comment: try onkeyup, onkeypress here will block your backspace and all other keys. Your requirement suits the onkeyup

Comment: @joyBlanks awesome Joy backspace is working but it not limiting the 15 characters it allow more than 15 characters....

Answer (score 0):

I have added few keystrokes that we use in the keyboard to bypass the logic such as tab backspace del etc to return false and then count how many chars you enter.

Please use `onkeypress="return checkEntry(event)"` in your div to check your requirement, also add the js function below to your JS.

```js
function checkEntry(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which ? e.which : e.charCode;
  var keyShorts = $.inArray(keyCode,new Array(8,9,13,16,17,18,19,20,27,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46,123,144,145))>-1;
  if(keyShorts){
    return true;
  }else if(e.target.innerHTML.replace(/(<|&lt;)br\s*\/*(>|&gt;)|(&nbsp;)/igm,' ').length>=15){
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid #ccc;" contenteditable=true onkeypress="return checkEntry(event)"></div>
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers.